# "Может" выделяется запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

*И пусть мне трудно, и может не сложится в итоге то, что давно задумано.*

Выделяется ли «может» запятыми?

Answer (score 2):

Да, выделяется с двух сторон запятыми как вводное предложение. Получается так:

***И пусть мне трудно, и, может, не сложится в итоге то, что давно задумано.***

---

Кстати, я бы ***пусть*** вставил и во второе предложение, сделав конструкцию такой:

***И пусть мне трудно, и пусть, может, не сложится в итоге то, что давно задумано.***

Comment: Может, как "вводное слово"...

Comment: Словарь вводных слов (Фрамполь) глаголы в функции вводных слов называет вводными предложениями. ("Я думаю" - двусоставное вводное, "может быть" - односоставное вводное). В этом есть смысл, потому что это фактически грамматические основы (подлежащие и сказуемые) предложений, "вкраплённые" в другие предложения.  "Я полагаю, что он идиот" - предложение.  Вычленяем предложение "я полагаю" и вставляем в любое другое предложения как выразитель субъективной модальности, т е. как вводную конструкцию. "Иван, я полагаю, зря убил лягушку". Конечно, вся эта реконструкция очень условна, но небессмысленна

Comment: Зачем отменять первые два? "К примеру" - вводное предложно-падежное сочетания, то самое "обычное вводное слово", а не предложение. Его нельзя представить в виде сказуемого. Пример вводного словосочетания - " с точки зрения" или "на самом деле" (именно словосочетания с сущ. и зависимым словом). А вводными предложениями там именуют только те, что что глаголами. Впрочем, это лишь точка зрения, и вы, ясное дело, с ней можете не соглашаться.

Comment: Странно. Есть вводные слова/словосочетания/предложения. Грамота считает иначе: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_417 Одно наречие тоже может быть предложением. Ну и что...

Comment: Когда наречие может быть предложением?

Comment: *— Как он подготовился? — Хорошо.*

Comment: Я бы сказал, что в вашем примере "хорошо" если и предложение, то двусоставное неполное, с отсутствующим подлежащим и сказуемым. (Как он подготовился? - Он хорошо подготовился. Поскольку в вопросе уже названы деятель и действие, то в ответе они опускаются, а остаётся лишь приглагольное наречие-обстоятельство). В любом случае слово "хорошо" в данном примере не является сказуемым, не имеет предикативности, а является обстоятельством при опущенном глаголе. Это даже не тянет на безличное предложение со словом состояния ("мне хорошо" или "хорошо тут у вас" или "хорошо быть тут").

Comment: И такой пример: *— Это точно? — Наверно.* Классификация в следующем: просто одно слово; устойчивые словосочетания, в которых слова нельзя изымать; предложения, в которых слова можно менять, убирать, добавлять. Такая классификация самая удачная.

Comment: У меня своя классификация: а) одиночные части речи в функции в вводных слов; б) словосочетания или устойчивые сочетания в функции вводных; в) вводные предложения глагольного типа, г) слова, которые с трудом идентифицируются частеречно и употребляются только как вводные. Я так привык.

Comment: Лучше использовать общепринятую классификацию, чтобы не возникало вопросов. Вот так предложение: *Он, вполне может быть, готовился.*

Comment: У тебя не возникнет вопросов по обособлению вводного слово. Задание ведь выполнено правильно, конструкция обособлена верно. У тебя возникли вопросы по теоретической интерпретации синтаксических явлений: что чем называть. А вот тут никто не может иметь единственно правильную точку зрения. Тут каждый мыслитель имеет право на своё, благо что на пунктуации это не сказывается никак.

Comment: Да, но "побеждает" большинство. А на белых ворон смотрят косо.

Comment: Быть "большинством" - высшая степень вульгарности. И нет никакого "большинства". Есть только ты со своим мнением. И я.

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно, обособление нужно.

А вообще, я бы поставил глагол в неопределённую форму — зазвучит гораздо плавнее и литературнее. Смысл, на мой взгляд, останется тем же. Запятая перед И тогда будет не нужна: "пусть" свяжет обе части. В первом случае "пусть" формально не относится ко второй части, но ведь очевидно, что по смыслу естественно отнести его и к ней. Тогда получится так:

> *И пусть мне трудно и может не сложиться в итоге то, что давно задумано.*

Естественным продолжением было бы: *Зато...*